# How to create an object of a nested class?

Tags: c++, oop, object, return

I am trying to access my nested class so I can return the object in this function:

```
Graph::Edge Graph::get_adj(int i)
{
    Graph::Edge v;
    int count = 0;
    for(list<Edge>::iterator iterator = adjList[i].begin(); count <= i ;++iterator)
    {
        v.m_vertex = iterator->m_vertex;
        v.m_weight = iterator->m_weight;
    }
    return v;
}
```

dont worry about the for loop (it should work theoreticly)  My main problem is with declaring the object `Graph::Edge v;`  It doesnt work!  This is the error I get:

```
$ make -f makefile.txt
g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -g -c Graph.cpp
Graph.cpp: In member function `Graph::Edge Graph::get_adj(int)':
Graph.cpp:124: error: no matching function for call to `Graph::Edge::Edge()'
Graph.cpp:43: note: candidates are: Graph::Edge::Edge(const Graph::Edge&)
Graph.h:27: note:                 Graph::Edge::Edge(std::string, int)
makefile.txt:9: recipe for target `Graph.o' failed
make: *** [Graph.o] Error 1
```

I want to access the

```
Graph.h:27: note:                 Graph::Edge::Edge(std::string, int)
```

Here is how my class Graph is declared: (I took out the functions and some of the things for simplicity and to make it easier to read)
*

```
class Graph
{
private:
    vector< list<Edge> > adjList;
public:
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    class Edge
    {
    public:
        Edge(string vertex, int weight)
        {
            m_vertex = vertex;
            m_weight = weight;
        }
        ~Edge(){}
        string m_vertex;
        int m_weight;
    };

    vector < list < Edge > > get_adjList(){return adjList;}
    //Other functions....

};
```

Basically, all I need to know is the correct way to declare an object of Edge in this function.  I am really confused and not sure what else to do other than Graph::Edge v;

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of `get_adj(i)`, should it return the whole adjacency list of vertex `i` or the `i`-th adjacency entry of the adjacency list of *some unspecified* vertex? I'm assuming your `adjList` is acutally a per-vertex adjacency list, meaning `adjList[i]` contains the adjacencies of vertex `i`.

Answer (score 5):

`Graph::Edge` does not have a default constructor (one that takes no arguments) - it has only a constructor that takes a `string` and an `int`. You either need to give a default constructor like so:

```
Edge()
{
  // ...
}
```

or pass a `string` and an `int` when constructing the object:

```
Graph::Edge v("foo", 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you've declared a constructor in the Edge class (`Edge(string vertex, int weight)`) and thus you do not have a default constructor. When you try to create an instance of the Edge class (which you do with `Graph::Edge v`), it tries to call this default constructor.

You need to either explicitly declare an `Edge()` default constructor or declare your variable using the constructor you've created.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that as `inner` is in `outer` class so `inner` object or instance can be created and method can be called like below snippet.

```c++
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class outer
{
    int x;
    public:
        class inner
        {
            public:
                void f(){
                    outer obj;
                    obj.x=10;
                    obj.display();
                }
        };
        void display()
        {
            cout<<x;
        }

};
int main(){
    outer::inner p;
    p.f();
    return 0;
}
//output=10
```